# generate choice switching matrix by group for many groups

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I want to calculate the choice switching probability by **group** first(`user` in below code). Then I will average the group level probability and get a total probability.  I have tens of thousands of groups so I need the code to be fast. My code is a `for loop` , which takes more than 10 minutes to run. I did the same code/logic excel, it takes less than a few seconds.

The `switching` for choice `m to n` for a particular user is defined as the share of observations whose choice are `n at period t` and `m at period t-1`
My original code is tagging the first and last purchase by for loop first. Then use another for loop to get the switching matrix. I am **only able** to create the switching matrix **by the whole data not by group**. Even so, it is still very slow. Adding user would make it even slower.

```
    t<-c(1,2,1,1,2,3,4,5)
    user<-c('A','A','B' ,'C','C','C','C','C')
    choice<-c(1,1,2,1,2,1,3,3)
    dt<-data.frame(t,user,choice)

    t user choice
    1   A   1
    2   A   1
    1   B   2
    1   C   1
    2   C   2
    3   C   1
    4   C   3
    5   C   3


    # **step one** create a second choice column for later construction of the switching matrix
    #Label first purchase and last purchase is zero
       for (i in 1:nrow(dt))
     { ifelse (dt$user[i+1]==dt$user[i],dt$newcol[i+1]<-0,dt$newcol[i+1]<-1) }


    # **step two** create stitching matrix 
    # switching.m is a empty matrix with the size of total chocie:3x3 here
  length(unique(dt$user))
total.choice<-3
switching.m<-matrix(0,nrow=total.choice,ncol=total.choice)

  for (i in 1:total.choice)
    {
    for(j in 1:total.choice)
      {
      if(length(nrow(switching.m[switching.m[,1]==i& switching.m[,2]==j,])!=0))
      {switching.m[i,j]=nrow(dt[dt[,1]==i&dt[,2]==j,])}

    else {switching.m[i,j]<0}
      }
  }
```

The desire output for a particular user/group is like this. The output should have the same matrix size even if the user does not make a particular choice at all

```
# take user C

#output for switching matrix
            second choice  
    first   1 2 3
    1       0 1 1
    2       1 0 0        
    3       0 0 1       

#output for switching probability
            second choice  
    first   1   2    3
    1       0 0.5 0.5
    2       1 0    0        
    3       0 0    1
```

Comment: @akrun, code added

Comment: For some reason, your code is throwing errors.  Please check the brackets.

Comment: Maybe try `lapply(split(dt$choice,dt$user),function(x) table(x[-length(x)],x[-1]))`.

Comment: @akrun now the code should work. I am not able to produce it by group. Only able to do it by the whole data set

Comment: Try split fir and then df %>%  group_by(user) %>%  mutate(Flag = as.integer(row_number() < 2)). After than you can user nrow to construct the matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `table` and `prop.table` after after `split`ting by 'user'

```
lst <- lapply(split(dt, dt$user), function(x)
     table(factor(x$choice, levels= 1:3), factor(c(x$choice[-1], NA), levels=1:3)))
```

As mentioned by @nicola, it is more compact to `split` the 'choice' column by 'user'

```
lst <- lapply(split(dt$choice, dt$user), function(x) 
       table(factor(x, levels = 1:3), factor(c(x[-1], NA), levels = 1:3))) 

lst$C

#  1 2 3
#1 0 1 1
#2 1 0 0
#3 0 0 1


prb <- lapply(lst, prop.table, 1)
prb$C

#     1   2   3
#  1 0.0 0.5 0.5
#  2 1.0 0.0 0.0
#  3 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

Comment: Basically the same I posted at the same time in the comments :) +1

Comment: @nicola Sorry, I didn't see your comment while posting this.  Possibly the page didn't update and I was busy posting this.

Comment: Don't worry, you couldn't. We made it at the same time. You could just split `dt$choice` instead the whole `data.frame` for efficiency (the splitting is lighter and in the `lapply` you don't have the `$` subset operation).